# Covariant return type for subclasses

Tags: dart

Beginner in Dart here.

```
abstract class Supertype {
  WithQuantity<Supertype> newQuantity(num quantity) =>
    WithQuantity(this, quantity)
}

class Subtype extends Supertype {
}

class WithQuantity<S extends Supertype> {
  final S thing;
  final num quantity;
  WithQuantity(this.thing, this.quantity);
}

void main() {
  WithQuantity<Subtype> quantityOfSubtype = Subtype().newQuantity(5);  
}
```

I'd like for the last line to compile.

In this version of course it doesn't, because `newQuantity` returns `WithQuantity<Supertype>`, not `WithQuantity<Subtype>`.

I can override the `newQuantity` method to make the return type narrower, but I'd have to do that for every subclass separately; seems duplicative.

In Java I could have done something like this:

```
class Supertype<S extends Supertype> {
  WithQuantity<S> newQuantity(...);
}
```

But Dart doesn't like this recursion.

Can I somehow tell the compiler that I need to return `WithQuantity<whateverMyRuntimeTypeIs>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `Supertype` as a generic whose type parameter is the subclass and then explicitly cast `this` to be that subclass type:

```dart
abstract class Supertype<S extends Supertype<S>> {
  WithQuantity<S> newQuantity(num quantity) =>
      WithQuantity(this as S, quantity);
}

class Subtype extends Supertype<Subtype> {}

class WithQuantity<S extends Supertype<S>> {
  final S thing;
  final num quantity;
  WithQuantity(this.thing, this.quantity);
}

void main() {
  WithQuantity<Subtype> listOfSubtype = Subtype().newQuantity(5);
}
```

Comment: wow, nice. So recursive definitions is fine, I just misunderstood the error, it was because I wrote Supertype<S extends Supertype>, instead of Supertype<S extends Supertype<S>>. And the strategically placed cast is great. Thank you very much James!